# Filtering between 2 date ranges in PivotTable VBA, works on one computer but not another

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, filtering, pivot-table

I am currently using the below code to filter a Pivot table between 2 dates.  It works fine on my computer but when a coworker tries it on theirs, it throws an error on the line that adds the filter. Whats weird is sometimes it errors on the PT2 line and sometimes on the PT3 line.  Any ideas on why this would work fine on one computer but not another?  I am using excel 2016 and I believe my coworker has the office excel 365 going.  The error the coworker is getting is Run-time error'1004': Application-defined or object defined error.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim ws6 as sheet, ws7 as sheet, ws9 as sheet
Dim PT2 As PivotTable, PT3 As PivotTable, PT5 As PivotTable
Dim PeriodStart As Variant, PeriodEnd As Variant


Set ws6 = Sheets("ProductivityDetailPivot")
Set ws7 = Sheets("ProductivityDetailPivotProcess")
Set ws9 = Sheets("ProductivityDetailPivotWeld")
Set PeriodStart = BegDateBox
Set PeriodEnd = EndDateBox
Set PT2 = ws6.PivotTables("ProductivityDetailPivot")
Set PT3 = ws7.PivotTables("ProductivityDetailPivotProcess")
Set PT5 = ws9.PivotTables("ProductivityDetailPivotWeld")

ws6.Activate
 PT2.PivotFields("Date"). _
        ClearAllFilters

 PT2.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters. _
        Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=PeriodStart, Value2:=PeriodEnd

PT2.RefreshTable

ws7.Activate
 PT3.PivotFields("Date"). _
        ClearAllFilters

 PT3.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters. _
        Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=PeriodStart, Value2:=PeriodEnd

PT3.RefreshTable
```

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: PT3.PivotFields("Date").PivotFilters. _
        Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=PeriodStart, Value2:=PeriodEnd

Comment: What are `BegDateBox` and `EndDateBox`?

Comment: Sorry forgot to put that in there, those are Dim'd as variants and they are values inside of combo boxes on one of the excel sheets.  When I attempt to debug, when the mouse is hovering over the values are the same on both computers.

Comment: I have also found that it works on machines using excel 2013 or 2016 but will throw the error code on excel 365

Comment: What does `Debug.Print IsDate(PeriodStart)` and `Debug.Print IsDate(PeriodEnd)` return in Excel 365?

Comment: @BigBen it returns 'true' for both of them